# NSMutableDictionary can't have "time" to read objects (NSMutableString s)

Tags: iphone, uilabel, nsmutabledictionary, nsmutablestring

I'am setting the text of labels with the content of NSMutableString_s which are objects of a NSMutableDictionray ... the problem that all things work fine when i load the page for two times (so i push ,after i pop...) and with the third push the program can't read the content of one of the NSMutableString_s of the NSMutableDictionary..so when it turns to the step of setting the value of the UILabel it didn't find the value...

there is the code where the exception appear:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableDictionary *item=[days objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *title1=[item objectForKey:@"week_day"];
    name1.text=title1;
    [title1 release];
```

Comment: This question very unclear. What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: From where is the data been set to the dictionary? If you are allocating the view again then the old data s gonna be lost. Please expand your question and post the code here

Comment: oki i am using an UISegmentedController with which i transit between two UIViewController (we note them 1 & 2) .First of all the view "1" appear with the UISegme... and when the user tapes the button 2 i push the "2" view ... the user want to return to "1" he tapes button "1" after he returns to the "2" ..to the "1" ... and when he tapes 2 to go further to 1 an exception occured saying that the program can't assign the text of an UILabel and this because the text got from NSMutableDictionary it isn't read yet (i discover this when debugging)
is it clear or i should give code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not release `title1` - you don't own the string returned by `-objectForKey:` and didn't take ownership by retaining it.
I suggest to read through the [Cocoa Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) to prevent that in the future.

Assuming that `text` is a `retain` property: with mutable strings, you should assign copies of the string to avoid them being changed under you:

```
NSString *title1 = [[item objectForKey:@"week_day"] copy];
name1.text = title1;
[title1 release]; // copy means taking ownership, so release
```

The following is a simplified example of what could be happening with your code as posted:

```
// entering -viewDidLoad the first time:
NSString *title1=[item objectForKey:@"week_day"];
// lets assume that the strings retain count is 1 here
name1.text=title1;
// setter retains, retain count now 2
[title1 release];
// retain count now 1

// entering -viewDidLoad the second time:
NSString *title1=[item objectForKey:@"week_day"];
// assuming nothing else did retain it, strings retain count is still 1
name1.text=title1;
// you assigned the same object, retain count still 1
[title1 release];
// strings retain count now 0 - will be deallocated :(
```

Comment: there is a link to an image which descibes the bug (when i am debugging) and you can remark that the program didn't assign a value to "title1" http://www.4shared.com/photo/ErtRxLwr/Picture_1.html
and i remind that all things worked fine when i pushed the view two times ago

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,
now it works fine when i escape the the transition with intermediate variables ,but what i didn't understood why it works for the two "pushing" actions before!!!

```
name1.text=[[days objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"week_day"];
```